# Custom list form progress indicator

Tags: html, newform

I have a list form that I customized and retrieves its design from HTML page, the thing is it doesn't look nice when the form is viewed until like 2 seconds when everything is loaded, how do I add a progress gif image or something to my form to let the user know that it's loading, then show the form?

Comment: [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) progress bar/indicator looks nice.

Comment: Is there an implementation of how it's built in newform or edit forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use PACE indicator to have the progress of the web page rendering which is nothing but a js which is used to present the rendering of pages but the disadvantage is that it will not work with older android OS.
There are various types like loading,center fold etc.